# Charging system issue 02 wrx

Tags: engine, electrical, subaru

Alternator is outputting 14 volts but not charging battery any ideas? Also the cable that connects from alternator to battery reads 14

Comment: Where does it read 14V? If the engine is not running, is there 12V at the alternator?

Comment: @SolarMike reads 14.35 when running at alt hot and 14.35 from where the alt wiring leads onto the positive battery terminal but the battery is just not getting the power

Comment: How old is the battery? It may have failed internally, either unexpectedly or from age-related degradation.

Comment: @David this battery is less than a week old from les Schwab

Comment: A battery can be 5 minutes old and still be knackered sorry defective.

Comment: What does the battery read when the engine is not running? Does the battery start the car? If it's putting out 14V, what makes you think it isn't charging?